# Callback inside angular directive is called before model updates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got directive with model and callback mapped to parent scope.
The problem is that parent model is updated AFTER callback occurs, but in code it is assigned BEFORE.

DEMO: [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/c33OEML7n6LdCY5XH4lk) 
(Click twice or more and you will see that model is updating after click callback)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = true;
  $scope.test2 = true;
  $scope.triggerCallback = function()
  {
      $scope.test2 = $scope.test;//it always see previous value here
  };
}).directive('testdirective', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<span ng-click="clicked()">from directive: {{checked}}</span>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            bindModel: '=ngModel',
            clickCallback: '&onClick'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.checked = scope.bindModel;

            scope.clicked = function () {
                scope.checked = !scope.checked; 
                scope.bindModel = scope.checked;//MODEL UPDATE


              //callback is called AFTER model updating, but model is updated after that
                if (scope.clickCallback != undefined)
                    scope.clickCallback();
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <a href="">
      <div testdirective ng-model="test" on-click="triggerCallback()"></div>
    </a>
    <br/>
    <span>{{test2}}</span>
  </body>
```

I know that I can do workaround and pass new value in callback function, but in some situations it is not enough - so I would like to resolve it straightforward

Comment: Why are you using `ngModel` for this? Only need `ng-model` for form controls

Comment: It just for naming convention, if it is used in e.g input type radio, why not in custom directive

Comment: @pawlakppp because it executes a bunch of code you don't need/want. `ng-model` is a directive like any other, with it's own logic. Logic that you don't use, but run anyway.

Comment: @Artless I see. Yeah so I better change it. Thanks

Comment: that is a terrible practice to use `ng-` for your own attributes. Also `replace` is deprecated.

Comment: Wouldn't have problems like this if you use objects in your scope models instead of primitives per best practices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a common two-way-data-binding mistake.

$scope.$apply is a solution, but maybe you get $digest already running exception. So you need to use $timeout, which will be executed, after the current digest-cycle has been finished.

```
$timeout(function(){
  if (scope.clickCallback != undefined) 
    scope.clickCallback(); 
  };
});
```

More information about angular lifecycle: http://onehungrymind.com/notes-on-angularjs-scope-life-cycle/

Comment: Unfortunately using scope.$apply gives me error: `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply`

Comment: Then remove these scope.applys and use $timeout(function(){if (scope.clickCallback != undefined)
                    scope.clickCallback();
            };});

Dont forget to inject $timeout into your Directive. So the function inside will be fired if the current digest-cycle is over (and your model-variable will be updated after the current digest-cycle)

Comment: can you update answer with that $timeout? It worked so that should be accepted answer, thanks!